# apply_filters() in plugin's constructor

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently trying to use filters that a plugin has offered to me.

The filter is supposed to be used in order to alter messages.

The problem is the apply_filters() function of the plugin is contained inside the plugin's constructor.
So my code is executed after all the plugins are loaded (functions.php -> filters.php) :

```
add_filter('plugin_filter_domain_filter_name', function ($baseText) {
    return 'Translated text';
}, 1, 3);
```

Do someone has already experienced something like that before ? I will be very thankful.

Comment: That sounds like a question for the plugin developer. They are the only ones who know where the filter is being called and if there is an alternative.

Comment: The apply filters func is inside public function __construct.

There is another apply filters being called outside of the plugin's constructor that is working well. But the constructor ones seems to be called very early, and so that's why I'm striving to use them.

Unfortunately the plugin dev isn't answring. :/